# Tooltips (Titles) in XUL browser content are not working?

Tags: firefox-addon, tooltip, xul

I'm developing an extension for FireFox. I use a [XUL `deck` element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XUL/deck) that contains a [XUL `browser` element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XUL/browser). Unfortunately, whenever the page displayed in the browser has an HTML [`title`](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_standard_title.asp) attribute, the value of this [`title`](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_standard_title.asp) attribute will not show up as a tooltip.

How can I get tooltips to display correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution for those who are interested, it's by adding a tooltip property to the XUL browser element with the following value:
 
        `tooltip="aHTMLTooltip"`

Or adding it programmatically using javascript like this:
        `browser.setAttribute('tooltip','aHTMLTooltip');`

for more details check: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=451792#c1

Comment: This works on panelview elements as well as the main browser. Seems a neater way to deal with the problem when building widgets, etc. for FF29/Australis. document.getElementById('my-panelview-element').setAttribute('tooltip','aHTMLTooltip');

Answer (score 1):

There is no mechanism to automatically display `title` attributes in tooltips - the browser window has special code for that and you need to replicate this code in your extension. This means that you need to define a [`<tooltip>` element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XUL/tooltip), e.g.:

```xml
<popupset>
  <tooltip id="browserTooltip" onpopupshowing="return fillTooltip(this);"/>
</popupset>
```

You should use this tooltip in your `<browser>` element, like this:

```xml
<browser tooltip="browserTooltip"/>
```

And you should create a `fillTooltip()` function that will be called whenever your tooltip shows up. It will need to look at the HTML element that the mouse pointer hovers over, check its `title` attribute and put the value of the attribute into the tooltip. The function performing this job in Firefox is [`FillInHTMLTooltip()`](http://hg.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/file/0e2cc686b07b/browser/base/content/browser.js#l3090) though you might want to go with a simpler variant like this (untested code):

```js
function fillTooltip(tooltip)
{
  // Walk up the DOM hierarchy until we find something with a title attribute 
  var node = document.tooltipNode;
  while (node && !node.hasAttribute("title"))
    node = node.parentNode;

  // Don't show tooltip if we didn't find anything
  if (!node)
    return false;

  // Fill in tooltip text and show it
  tooltip.setAttribute("label", node.getAttribute("title"));
  return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Working example:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?xml-stylesheet href="chrome://global/skin" type="text/css"?>
<window id="mainWindow" xmlns="http://www.mozilla.org/keymaster/gatekeeper/there.is.only.xul" title="NanoFL" width="800" height="600" persist="screenX screenY width height sizemode">
<script>
    <![CDATA[

    function fillTooltip(tooltip)
    {
        var nodes = document.getElementById("browser").contentWindow.document.querySelectorAll(":hover");
        for (var i=nodes.length-1; i>=0; i--)
        {
            if (nodes[i].hasAttribute("title"))
            {
                tooltip.setAttribute("label", nodes[i].getAttribute("title"));
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    ]]>
</script>
<browser id="browser" src="chrome://nanofl/content/index.html" flex="1" disablehistory="true" tooltip="browserTooltip" />
<tooltip id="browserTooltip" onpopupshowing="return fillTooltip(this)"/>
</window>
```